# IPython notebook: define a dummy cell magic that simply runs the cell as usual

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel, ipython-magic

How can I define a simple cell magic that just executes the cell as if the `%%mymagic` wasn't there?

The context is that we are using the wonderful [IPython parallel](http://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel) framework.  In some places, we also use its defined `%%px` magic.  But sometimes we'd like to run the same notebook without a cluster (local only).  In that case, `%%px` isn't defined and I would have to comment it out.  Instead, in that case I'd like to redefine `%%px` so that:

- `%%px`: would be a no-op.
- `%%px --local`: just runs the cell, no other side-effect.

Alternatively, all `%%px` (with `--local` or not) could just run the cell, if that's simpler.

Another approach would be to create an ipyparallel Client that is a fake one, i.e. with 0 nodes (but would still operate correctly, e.g. with regard to `%%px --local`). But that would be for another question.

**Things I've tried**:

- `%alias_magic px time` (after all, I don't care if the cell is timed). Unfortunately, `%%time` doesn't take arguments and chokes on `--local`.
- Define my own "no-op" magic:

  ```
  if USE_CLIENT:
      pass
  else:
      # temporarily define %%px cell magic
      from IPython import get_ipython
      def px(line, cell):
          """Do nothing"""
          pass

      get_ipython().register_magic_function(px, 'cell')
  ```

  but that succeeds a little too well at doing *really nothing* (i.e. the cells are not executed).
- Look into [IPython/core/magics/execution.py](http://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py) to see if there is any hook I could reuse (something that would just execute the cell). I haven't found, but perhaps I haven't looked hard enough.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think the relevant command is

> self.shell.run_cell(cell)

Answer (score 1):

We can define a magic command that just does not have effect as:

```
def f(line, cell):
    print('==> line:[{}]'.format(line))
    print('==> cell:\n    # {}'.format('\n    # '.join(cell.split())))
    print('==================================================================')
    res = get_ipython().run_cell(cell)

get_ipython().register_magic_function(f, 'cell', 'cache')
```

Here is an example run:
[image]

In your case, try:

```
if USE_CLIENT:
    pass
else:
    # temporarily define %%px cell magic
    from IPython import get_ipython
    def px(line, cell):
         res = get_ipython().run_cell(cell)
    get_ipython().register_magic_function(px,'cell','px')
```

Comment: And of course use `line` to create a line magic (*mostly as a note to self*)